# Android:Multi touch event handling is supported in Android 1.6 SDK?

Tags: android

Friends,

I like to know using which version of Android SDK we can develop multi touch handling. Does Android SDK 1.6 support multi touch? If yes, can i get some sample code, where i can have multiple imagebuttons placed on screen and clicking on all the imagebuttons at a time should detect multiple touch events?

Thank you.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think its an update with the 2.1. Why do you want to try on 1.6 at this point any way?

Comment: Because one of the issues with Android is that different handsets come with different versions of the OS, and not all of them are good at making sure people upgrade in a timely manner. At least, that's how it was a few months ago.

Comment: For instance, the apps I work on target 1.6 since that's the safest bet. Unless I need a feature from a newer version of the OS I'm going to support the oldest feasible version I can in an effort to not cut off part of the market for no reason.

Comment: 1.6 added gesture support.  I don't think full multitouch was supported until 2.0.  As for @schar's comment, 2.1-update-1 just added pinch-zoom in a few Google apps, support for writing apps that were multitouch enabled was already in the API.  There are several games that use multitouch that work perfectly on Motorola Droids on 2.0.1.

Comment: Actually, it's not the users fault we don't upgrade. 2.1 has yet to be released for the G1, that's why everyone's still using 1.6

Comment: After all your replies, i finalize that Android 1.6 SDK doesn't support multi touch handling. Please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: @user187532 You are right. I would still suggest you to test your app written for 1.6 apps on 2.1. I have seen some apps in the market that dont run on 2.1 and that generally leaves a remark on your app.
Remember that the Droid/Nexus one user base is quite high.

Comment: Just to add some confusion - the HTC Hero, which uses their customised Sense interface but still runs Android 1.5, supports multi touch. I haven't tested with other applications, but you can definitely do the pinch-zoom in the browser.

Comment: The SDK multitouch APIs were introduced in 2.0.  Anything that does multitouch on a platform before that is not using the SDK and thus likely to break on different devices.

Answer (score -2):

Yes.
Have a look here: http://lukehutch.wordpress.com/2010/01/06/my-multi-touch-code-ported-to-eclair/.

Comment: The backported version compiles for 1.5/1.6, but is only functional with the appropriate kernel updates - like with cyanogenmod.